# return the first item of a sublist that has the maximum value at the third column

Tags: python, list, loops, nested-loops

I have this list as an example

`favourite_candy_boys_girls = [['Chips' , 1, 2], ['Chocolate', 3, 4], ['Lollipops', 2, 4]]`

The second column refers to boys and the third column refers to girls. I want write a function where I return the first candy in which girls like the most (in this case it should be Chocolate). I know if I run the following:

`max(l[2] for l in favourite_candy_boys_girls)`

I would find the max but I'm not too sure how to return the candy

EDIT
I'm thinking of writing it as a function using loops like so:

```
>>> def get_candy_with_max_girls(Candy: SystemData):
    """Return the candy type that has the most girls.
     If there is a tie of girls for a particular candy type, return the 
     candy type that appears first in candy.

>>> get_candy_with_max_girls(favourite_candy_boys_girls):
'Chocolate'
 """
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `key` argument of the max function. It allows you to give a function that will be used on your items before sorting them:

```
l = [['Chips' , 1, 2], ['Chocolate', 3, 4], ['Lollipops', 2, 4]]
max(l, key=lambda x: x[2])[0]  
# returns 'Chocolate'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a dictionary instead, with the key being the food item, you can use this code:

```
testlist = {"Chips":[1,2],"Chocolate":[3,4]}

output = max(testlist, key=lambda x: testlist[x][-1])
print output
```

Which outputs:

```
Chocolate
```

Comment: @DRPK that is correct, I missed the point that order matters for OP. Going to leave code so a future reader can avoid this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try This ( No library Needed, works for girls and boys and also works for multi max candies values ):

```
favourite_candy_boys_girls = [['Chips', 1, 2], ['Chocolate', 3, 4], ['Lollipops', 2, 4], ["gumdrop", 3, 4]]


my_dict = {}

# Convert Your List to Dictionary
for candy_box in favourite_candy_boys_girls:
    my_dict[candy_box[0]] = {"Girls": candy_box[1], "Boys": candy_box[2]}


def the_most_delicious_candy(get_dict, girl_or_boy):

    if girl_or_boy == "girls":

        just_girls = {}
        for candy, values in get_dict.items():
            just_girls[candy] = values["Girls"]

        find_max = max(just_girls.values())

        last_buffer = []
        for candy, values in get_dict.items():

            if values['Girls'] == find_max:

                make_new_dict = { candy: get_dict[candy] }
                last_buffer.append(make_new_dict)

        return last_buffer

    elif girl_or_boy == "boys":

        just_boys = {}
        for candy, values in get_dict.items():
            just_boys[candy] = values["Boys"]

        find_max = max(just_boys.values())

        last_buffer = []
        for candy, values in get_dict.items():

            if values['Boys'] == find_max:
                make_new_dict = {candy: get_dict[candy]}
                last_buffer.append(make_new_dict)

        return last_buffer

    else:
        return "Just Girls and Boys are available"
```

Call for boys :

```
print(the_most_delicious_candy(my_dict, "boys"))
```

**BOYS OUTPUT:**

```
[{'Chocolate': {'Boys': 4, 'Girls': 3}}, {'Lollipops': {'Boys': 4, 'Girls': 2}}, {'gumdrop': {'Boys': 4, 'Girls': 3}}]
```

Call For Girls:

```
print(the_most_delicious_candy(my_dict, "girls"))
```

**GIRLS OUTPUT:**

```
[{'gumdrop': {'Boys': 4, 'Girls': 3}}, {'Chocolate': {'Boys': 4, 'Girls': 3}}]
```

Good Luck ...

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
favourite_candy_boys_girls = [['Chips' , 1, 2], ['Chocolate', 3, 4], ['Lollipops', 2, 4]]
max(favourite_candy_boys_girls, key=lambda x: x[2])[0]
# 'Chocolate'
```

The max call gives you the triplet with the max girls via the key function. Then you just grap the candy of that triplet.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a key while doing max

```
def get_candy_with_max_girls(favourite_candy_boys_girls):
    return max(favourite_candy_boys_girls, key = lambda k:k[2])[0]
```